# Code Igniter flexi auth user_update

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I use Codeigniter 2.1.3 and flexi_auth. Add user, delete user, login, rules works. But when I try update data as username or password by update_user function. This function return me true, but in database nothing is changed.

Maybe whoever had similar problem and know, how solve this issue?

```
$user = array('username'=>'newusername'); or $user = array('password'=>'newpassword');     
$this->flexi_auth->update_user($user_id,$user);
```

I know that to change password exist other function. But required is old password. I'd like change password without old confirmation.

Comment: can you show your update function?

Comment: Simple version:
`protected function upd($userId,$newLogin){
$user = array('username'=>$newLogin);
return $this->flexi_auth->update_user($userId,$user);
}`